# Grails mail plugin issues with Gmail SMTP

Tags: email, grails, grails-3.0

I'm using the grails mail plugin (2.0.0.RC2) with Grails 3.0.7. This is my config:

```
mail:
        host: smtp.gmail.com
        port: 465
        username: myuser@gmail.com
        password: myPassword
        props:
          - mail.debug: true
          - mail.smtp.auth: true
          - mail.smtp.socketFactory.port: 465
          - mail.smtp.socketFactory.class: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
          - mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback: false
```

When I try to send a test mail, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:131) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:55) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:59) ~[mail-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at com.eduspace.ClassroomController.$tt__index(ClassroomController.groovy:13) ~[main/:na]
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:90) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972) ~[javax.mail-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656) ~[javax.mail-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) ~[javax.mail-api-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I see no other debug information in the logs. I have the root logger set to INFO, so everything should be getting outputted. I've verified that I can telnet to smtp.gmail.com port 465, so that's not the issue. I've read that others have had issues with SSL, but then there's usually some debug information indicating an SSL issue and I don't get anything like that.

Comment: It might be causing by your AntiVirus. I had this issue and the reason was *Avast Mail Shield*

Comment: I don't have any antivirus turned on at the moment. I did try to open a socket to smtp.gmail.com on port 465 in my Grails app and was able to do that, so I know it can connect.

Comment: what is the colon notation used here?  I thought the config.groovy had to be something like grails { mail { host = .... } }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using a slightly different config that works fine:

```
grails:
    mail:
        host: "smtp.gmail.com"
        port: 465
        username: "<username>@gmail.com"
        password: "<password>"
        props:
            mail.smtp.auth: "true"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.port: "465"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.class: "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback: "false"
```

The mail config is inside in the **grails** placeholder and i am not using the dashes as in your example. Maybe this could be of help to you.

Comment: Strangely enough, removing the dashes worked...However, I thought those properties were supposed to be a list, and in YAML a list is represented by dashes, so not sure there :) In any case, it's working now!

Comment: Finally this helped me! I was also using the props settings incorrect using dashes and also brackets. Still got an error about not able to connect to gmail. In my case I needed to also use `mail.smtp.ssl.enable: "true"` Then I was able to connect and send messages.

Comment: Thank you. It's now working after fixing the "props" as above.

Answer (score 4):

This could ofcourse be wrong due to config error but one of the reason for this exact error message is gmail configuration. To avoid spam messages, gmail has started blocking access from apps that do not conform to latest security guidelines.

One easy way to avoid this error is to go to your gmail account and allow less secure apps.- https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks good.

Here is the mine working fine:

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        'default' {
            from = "<username>@gmail.com"
        }
        port = 465
        username = "<username>@gmail.com"
        password = "<password>"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                      
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}
```